# Ruby REPL, determinate if a line it's part of a valid expression

Tags: ruby, expression, read-eval-print-loop, lexical-analysis

I'm doing a Ruby REPL (just a hobby, won't be big and professional like [pry](http://pryrepl.org/)).

I wrote a very simple REPL that works fine if the input it's just a single valid line of Ruby:

```
loop do
  print "ruby> "
  input = gets
  puts "=> #{eval(input)}"
end
```

**I want to support multiline inputs.**

One approach that I'm thinking is to check for each input line if the code is a correct Ruby expression, part of a Ruby expression or invalid code.

```
valid_expression?("def foo; end") # => true, complete expression
valid_expression?("def foo")      # => true, partial expression
valid_expression?("def ::foo")    # => false
```

Anyway, I tried to understand other implementations<sup>[1](https://github.com/janlelis/ripl-multi_line/blob/master/lib/ripl/multi_line/irb.rb),[2](https://github.com/janlelis/ripl-multi_line/blob/master/lib/ripl/multi_line/ripper.rb),[3](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/master/samples/expert-irb.rb)</sup> but is really difficult/undocumented code. Maybe I can use `RubyLex` or `Ripper`.

Ideally, I'm interesting to use Ruby standard libraries without any external gem. It doesn't matter if only target for Ruby 2.x versions, but if there is a gem to do the work, I'll happy to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you noticed that there is pry, you should look its source and learn from it. Actually, pry does internally use such method as you described. It is: [`MethodSource::CodeHelpers#complete_expression?`](https://github.com/banister/method_source/blob/master/lib/method_source/code_helpers.rb).